# MYSQL get all result from "where in"

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

**table_city**

```
id - name
1  - rome
2  - london
3  - paris
```

**table_category**

```
id - id_city - category
1  - 1       - red
2  - 1       - blue
3  - 3       - red
```

Then I need to select city on category select...
This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM table_city WHERE id IN ( 
  SELECT id_city FROM table_category WHERE category LIKE 'red' )
```

and this work... But how if I want all city?

```
SELECT * FROM table_city WHERE id IN ( 
  SELECT id_city FROM table_category WHERE category LIKE '%' )
```

this select doesn't return london...

Comment: Your table table_category does not make sense. You should have a third table. Look up many-to-many relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` doesn't return london because of the inner query:

```
SELECT id_city FROM table_category WHERE category LIKE '%'
```

`table_category` column contain `1, 1, 3`, there is no entry of `2` i.e. for london in it. That's why you are not getting london.

To resolve this issue, use `left join` instead of inner query by keeping the table `table_city` in left.

Comment: The real solution is to fix the table design.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample data of table_category there is no record that has id_city mapping to london and hence you are not able to see london with the query 
SELECT * FROM table_city WHERE id IN ( 
  SELECT id_city FROM table_category WHERE category LIKE '%' )
If we break the query

SELECT id_city FROM table_category WHERE category LIKE '%' will return 1,1,3

SELECT * FROM table_city WHERE id IN (1,1,3) will return Rome and Paris

Answer (score 0):

Your First query returns the value

> `+----+-------+`

```
|  1 | rome  |
|  3 | paris |
```

your inside query returns the value

> `+--------+`

```
| 1      |
| 3      |
```

`+--------+`

There is no connection with your inside query to the table_city,
as there is no entry for '2' in the id_city column.
Even if you select category-blue.. it will still show rome as the id_city which is 1 matches with only Rome in the table_city.
Hence it is not able to query all the cities.